# Why is a unipotent reflection normalizing a algebraic group $G \subset SL(V)$, an element of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I´m working myself right now through this [article](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Edrinfeld/Hypergeometric_motives/Beukers-Heckman.pdf) and have a question regarding the proof of Proposition 6.4, case II) on page 345-346. I try to give a short outline of the situation:

---

We have $G \subset SL(V)$ a connected algebraic group, acting irreducible on a complex vectorspace $V$ and a reflection $r \in GL(V)$ which normalizes $G$ and has special eigenvalue $c \in \mathbb{C}^*$.

*Note: As a reflection we understand a linear map $r \in GL(V)$ such that $r-Id$ has rank one, and its determinant is called the special eigenvalue. So what the author refers to as "reflection", are actually [pseudo-reflections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreflection).*

In the proof we consider the Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$, which is semisimple and also acts irreducible on $V$. And now at the beginning of case II) we consider $c=+1$, and $r$ thus becomes an unipotent element. Then there is the following statement, which i don´t understand, and want to verify now:

**Since $r$ is an unipotent element, we have in fact $r \in G$ and $log(r)=(r-Id) \in \mathfrak{g}$.**

Comment: This is a very odd way to say that $r=Id$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I think what the author refers to as "reflection" are actually pseudo-reflections.

Comment: I see, you are right, they are using a nonstandard definition of a reflection